# Apache ActiveMQ Server startup issue in windows 7

Tags: apache, activemq-classic

```
jvm 1    |  WARN | Store limit is 102400 mb, whilst the data directory: C:\apach
e-activemq-5.8.0\bin\win32\..\..\data\kahadb only has 44093 mb of usable space

jvm 1    | ERROR | Temporary Store limit is 51200 mb, whilst the temporary data
directory: C:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\win32\..\..\data\localhost\tmp_storage o
nly has 44093 mb of usable space
```

Comment: When i am trying to run activemq batch file in bin win32  folder it is showing the above error message...

Comment: I am having 40GB of free space in my C:/ drive...How to resolve this problem...Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that your configured limits don't fit with the amount of disk space you have available at the store location.  This can lead to Broker failure in older versions as the limits are not lowered automatically to match the disk space, in the latest release the broker will lower the limits.  When you see this it means you should either rethink you store location, or your broker config.